# MySQl comulative count with group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a simple query that counts the number of times a client has been called by agent.

```
Call_ID  | Lead_id | Agent
1        | 1       | madison
2        | 1       | Kelly
3        | 2       | madison
4        | 1       | Sam
```

I need to add another column called call_attempt which would be unique to each agent and lead

```
Call_ID  | Lead_id | Agent   | call attempt
1        | 1       | madison | 1
2        | 1       | Kelly   | 2
3        | 2       | madison | 1
4        | 1       | Sam     | 3
```

Comment: Does this just need to be populated once into the table, or does it need to be updated every time records are modified in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a query with ugly performance but here you are anyway:

```
select t1.call_id, t1.lead_id, t1.agent, 
       (select count(*) from THETABLE t2
         where t2.lead_id=t1.lead_id
          and t2.call_id <= t1.call_id)
from THETABLE t1
```

**UPDATE:**

A query with enhanced performance:

```
select t1.call_id, t1.lead_id, t1.agent, 
       count(t2.call_id) as cum_sum
from THETABLE t1
inner join THETABLE t2
  on t2.lead_id=t1.lead_id
   and t2.call_id <= t1.call_id
group by t1.call_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of calls by the lead_id that appear previously in the table to calculate the ranking, and update into the new `call_attempt` field with a query like the following:

```
update calls c
   set call_attempt = 
       (select count(Lead_id) from calls c2
        where c.Lead_id = c2.Lead_id and c2.Call_ID <= c.Call_ID);
```

Here is a demontsration: http://sqlize.com/fXn4p2cc5j

Answer (score 0):

For the first half of your question:

```
SELECT Lead_id, Agent, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfCalls
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Lead_id, Agent
```

For the second half, I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: It sounds like OP would like the `call attempt` column to be a ranking/ordering over `Lead_id`, and it needs to be calculated and updated back into the table.

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection?

Comment: @mellamokb If that's what OP is going for, I'd discourage them from attempting to store that kind of data directly in the table. It just becomes too big a headache to keep it updated.

Comment: I agree.  I'm not the downvoter, but the reason is probably your answer doesn't really answer the "underlying" (unobvious) question - how to get ranking per Lead_id into the table.  Provide a suggestion on how this should *really* be done - since you're the SQL guru - and you'll get my vote :-)

Comment: @JoeStefanelli, thanks for your input. if i was to not store that data, but use it in a query, or a view, how would i create it. i could add it to a chron job and make a table and query that table but i have no idea how to create it.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli I am the downvoter. I suppose you did not really expect an upvote, did you? You answered a question you did not understand and even then you provided an answer to only a part of it (and it wasn't really a two part question). Your answer is therefore not only useless but also confusing for future readers and I decided this objection was worth -1 for me to downvote it.